# Multiple HttpWebRequests on single connection

Tags: c#, connection, client, httpwebrequest

So I'm trying to write a client for a specific Server, imitating the behavior of what I see in the dev tools of browsers like Chrome and Firefox. I'm using HttpWebRequest and it seems to work great for me for an INDIVIDUAL exchange, but as soon as I need to make use of another it never works. I figured that I would just need to store my ConnectionToken so that the Server could recognize me as the same client across multiple requests, but that clearly is not the case. Here is an example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


namespace WebClient
{
    class WebClientProgram
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //FIRST REQUEST, NEGOTIATE
            DateTime unixStart = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1), DateTimeKind.Utc);
            long epoch = (long)Math.Floor((DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - unixStart).TotalSeconds);
            String timestamp = Convert.ToString(epoch);
            String uri = "http://domain/signalr/negotiate?_=" + timestamp;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            //Set REQUEST values
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.KeepAlive = true;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            JavaScriptSerializer jSerialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Dictionary<string, string> responseDictionary = jSerialize.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            String connectionToken = responseDictionary["ConnectionToken"];//Save my unique connection token
            String connectionID = responseDictionary["ConnectionId"];
            String protocolVersion = responseDictionary["ProtocolVersion"];

            //SECOND REQUEST, START
            epoch = (long)Math.Floor((DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - unixStart).TotalSeconds);
            timestamp = Convert.ToString(epoch);
            uri = "http://domain/signalr/start?clientProtocol=" + protocolVersion + "&connectionToken=" + connectionToken + "&_=" + timestamp;
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            //Set REQUEST values
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.KeepAlive = true;

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();//On this line I receive a 400 error from the server
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            File.WriteAllText(@"start.txt", reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

So this is me trying to do a basic exchange for a SignalR server, which is what I'm trying to attach to. I first NEGOTIATE and get back a distinct ConnectionToken that I use for the following request. That following request, however, always runs into a response "400: The connection-id is in the incorrect format".
Any thoughts? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your code, are you missing the ampersand in the url?

`"&connectionToken=" + connectionToken + "`**here**`_=" + timestamp`

Comment: Ah, when I was copying-pasting from my code to here I removed some of the more personal details of the url and accidentally erased that ampersand. It actually is included in my code and the error still persists. Good spotting though! I'll change the code here to reflect that.

Comment: This should have been a comment. Please delete this answer - it cost me 20 seconds to figure out whether it's relevant. Code has been fixed. Thanks.